# TypeError: 'SArray' object does not support item assignment?

Tags: python, pandas, graphlab

I am working on `graphlab` and geeting problems in all kind of assignments using `SFrame`, which are like `dataframe` and series objects are `SArrays`. Each time I have to convert the whole data to `dataframe` and again to `SFrame`.

```
import graphlab as gl
sf = gl.SFrame('abc.csv') # have columns 'Name','Price', 'Quantity' etc.
for i in range(0, len(sf)):
    temp = (str)sf['Name'][i]
    temp = temp.replace('_br_', '')
    sf['Name'][i] = temp
```

Now, I wanted to do some string operations and matching, but first I can't even assign values to SArray.
Any advice on how to simplify item assignment using `SFrame` or alternative apart from `dataframe` would be helpful.